# FS mounted as RO on boot after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, mount, lightdm, 15.04

Just upgraded from 14.10 to 15.04.
Couldn't get the system to boot ok.
I could boot using (upstart) option - not using default systemd.
When in default mode the lightdm terminal was stuck before login screen.
I could switch to TTY though.
I found out finally that in TTY i can run:
`$ mount -rw -o remount /`

This causes the lightdm service to continue to login screen and I can work normally.
However I now have to do that manually each reboot...

Also I tryed checing the FS using fsck and everything is OK.

Any thoughts?

EDIT - This is the content of my /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation

/dev/disk/by-label/data /mnt/data ext4 nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
/dev/disk/by-label/backup /mnt/backup ext4 nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

Comment: Edit your question and post the content of your `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Try my answer, thats how I fixed that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Once you're sucessfully logged on to Ubuntu. Open a Terminal (**Ctrl+Alt+T**)  followed by:-

```
sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Edit the line that looks like

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-x.x.x-xx-generic root=xxx\xyz ro xxx-options
```

to

`linux /boot/vmlinuz-x.x.x-xx-generic root=xxx\xyz rw xxx-options`

This file is generated from the files present in /etc/grub.d and therefore you'll need to edit this each time you update or make changes to grub.

Comment: This has to be repeatedly reapplied because it is a bodge.  The root filesystem is _supposed_ to be mounted read-only, and then remounted read-write by `systemd-remount-fs.service` after `systemd-fsck-root.service`.  If that's not happening then something is wrong.  Bodging around it doesn't fix the actual problem, whatever it may be.

Comment: as @JdeBP says - I wouldn't want a workaround - if there's something wrong I rather find and fix it. but 10x.