# Stuck on booting

Tags: grub2, gnu

I am new to ubuntu. I am getting GNU GRUB screen on my computer while I am starting it and i can't get out of it.
I tried removing quiet splash with nomodeset and then pressing ctrl+x but it's giving
/bin/sh: 0 can't access tty; job control turned off

Comment: It once happened to me, try mounting system as 'rw' using advanced boot

Comment: Can please elaborate

Comment: Try this:- https://askubuntu.com/a/624557/408593

Comment: You may need to go into recovery to access terminal:- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: This is what i get when i press ENTER on recovery mode. [   4.447039] ---[ end Kernl panic - not syncing : Attempted to kill init! exit code = 0x00007f00      [4.447039]

Comment: Would it solve the problem if i reinstall Ubuntu again?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/592285/408593

Comment: What amount of ram do you have?

Comment: 2GB RAM, 500GB Hard disk, Intel Celeron 1.5 GHz processor. I have currently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit. It was working fine since last 30 days when I first installed it.

Comment: I am getting this problem since yesterday